# BigQuery - Cast HEX string to NUMERIC or BIGNUMERIC?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, type-conversion

I've got a data string in a hex format.  Something like

```
'0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006cc09155dd769741d7cd1c6a3334a1aeef62da2d0e92a39230becd6e56c2ad490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007ce66c50e2840000' as data
```

I know that `substring(data, 131)` is a large number.

I can pass `SAFE_CAST(CONCAT('0x', SUBSTRING(data, 131)) AS INT64)` just fine on the smaller numbers.

`SAFE_CAST(CONCAT('0x', SUBSTRING(data, 131)) AS NUMERIC)` (or bignumeric) won't work.

I tried something like `FROM_HEX(SUBSTRING(data, 131))` to get a byte format.  But couldn't find any good options for getting `BYTE` to `NUMERIC` either.

Comment: I'm not sure your goal will succeed.  The hex data you are seeing is a portable way to pass data without resorting to bytes/binary.  I don't think you'll be able to transform this to a number.  What does the data represent?  What will you do with it once it was a number?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Basically just arithmetic. The data will be any number of 32 byte pieces of information together in a string. 

`0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000009ed194db19b238c000000`

In this case I know it's `12000000000000000000000000`

Just don't know how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such big numbers, not even `BIGNUMERIC` will fit them, so you will have to work as string. Regular BigQUery functions will not be able to handle that numbers, so I suggest you to use a `UDF`:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION from_hex_to_intstring(hex STRING)
RETURNS STRING   
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
    yourNumber = BigInt(hex,16);
    return yourNumber;
  """;

select from_hex_to_intstring('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006cc09155dd769741d7cd1c6a3334a1aeef62da2d0e92a39230becd6e56c2ad490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007ce66c50e2840000') data;
select  from_hex_to_intstring('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000009ed194db19b238c000000') data
```

**Results:**

```
-------------------------------
Row | data  
1   | 5695815805094697319662327076913960577653781492348607706655047793592681546373383993595483025021696631917691807178407718241565809060633202962632700189736960
-------------------------------
Row | data  
1   | 12000000000000000000000000
-------------------------------
```

**Bonus 1:**
If the hex is not that big you can return it as `NUMERIC` or `BIGNUMERIC` with:

```
select cast(from_hex_to_intstring(<hex string>) as NUMERIC)
```

**Bonus 2:**
If you want to trim the zeros on your hex use the following *(But its not required for the function above)*:

```sql
select concat("0x",ltrim('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000009ed194db19b238c000000',"0x")) as data
```

```
-------------------------------
Row | data  
1   | 0x9ed194db19b238c000000
-------------------------------
```

- I recommend you to work only with string, not cast to NUMERIC.